# Plot a set of complex numbers with given argument and absolute value bounds

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to plot the following complex numbers $$z \in \text{(complex numbers)}:\pi/4 < \arg (z) \leq 5 \pi/4,\ 1 \leq |z| < 2 $$

I don't know how to graph it so that it would look like 2D without any unecessary details. The closest approach I found is parametric function plotting. I tried to use `ContourPlot` to graph it, but I just can't seem to do it...

```
ContourPlot[
 Im[F[z[x, y]]], 
 {3 pi/4 < arg (z) <= 5 pi/4, 
  1 <= abs (z) < 2}, 
 {x, -.2, .2}, {y, -.2, .2}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Contours -> Range[-5, 5, .5], 
 ContourLabels -> True
]
```

Does anybody know how to graph my set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With correct Mathematica syntax and increased range of x,y `RegionPlot` solves your problem:

```
RegionPlot[ 3 Pi/4 < Arg[x + I y] <= 5 Pi/4 && 1 <= Abs [x + I y] < 2 , {x, - 2,2}, {y, - 2, 2} ]
```

[image]

**addendum**

Thanks to the comment @Bili Debili: Arg returns angle in the range `-Pi...Pi`, that's why the condition `3 Pi/4 < Arg[x + I y] <= 5 Pi/4` has to be changed

```
RegionPlot[3 Pi/4 < Abs[Arg[ x + I y]] <= Pi &&1 <= Abs [x + I y] < 2 , {x, - 2, 2}, {y, - 2, 2} ,FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the function also go into the third quadrant ?

Comment: That's right, thanks. `Arg[…]` lies in the range `-Pi,Pi`

Answer (score 3):

```
ParametricPlot[
 ReIm[r*Exp[I*θ]], {θ, π/4, (5 π)/4}, {r, 1, 2},
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{π/4, {Thick, Blue, Dashed}}, {(5 π)/
     4, {Thick, Blue}}}, {{1, {Thick, Red}}, {2, {Thick, Red, 
      Dashed}}}}, BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> Yellow]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One more way is as follows.

```
ComplexRegionPlot[ Pi/4 < Arg [z] <= 5 Pi/4 && 1 <= Abs [z] < 2, {z, -2 - 0*I, 2 + 2*I},AspectRatio->Automatic]
```